# How to create new VMs in Horizon View PowerCLI?

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, powercli, horizon

I'm trying to create new virtual machines inside an existing pool using the Horizon View PowerCLI.  Although, after looking at all the cmdlets from that module, there doesn't seem to be a way to create a new machine (Like a 'new-HVmachine' command or something like that).  I have the VMware.HV.Helper module and did a "get-command *HV*" to see all the cmdlets.

Does anybody know how I would create these new VMs?  Any help/input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You mean creating a VM with Powercli?
First you have to connect to your datacenter

```
Connect-VIServer -Server "" -Protocol https -User "" -Password ""
```

Then run the command New-VM

```
New-VM -Name 'VMName' –VMHost 'VMHost' -Datastore 'Datastore' -DiskGB 40 -MemoryGB 8 -NumCpu 2 -NetworkName 'Virtual Machine Network'
```

for more information on New-VM command : [NEW-VM by VMware](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/New-VM.html)

Comment: @StefTheo...This is close, but not quite what I was looking for.  Connect-viServer is for vShere and Connect-HVServer is for Horizon View (which is what I need the cmdlet for).  My co-worker actually just figured it out.  The cmdlet that creates a VM in an existing pool is Add-HVDesktop.  I originally thought that this cmdlet only adds an already-made VM to a pool, not create it.    The code that worked is 'Add-HVDesktop -poolname <pool name> -machines <name of new VM> -users <Active Directory you are assigning VM to>'  Thank you for your help!!